# Python: how to get the first file in directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7, listdir

So I want to grab the first file under a directory in Python. I know I can do like this:

```
first_file = [join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))][0]
```

But it's slow. Is there any better solution? Thanks!

Comment: thanks @gtlambert. Very quick indeed. I was just about to edit it :P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
first_file = next(join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f)))
```

Note that if there are no files in the directory it would throw `StopIteration` exception. Either handle it, or provide a *default value*:

```
first_file = next((join(path, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))), 
                  "default value here")
```

Comment: oh, does the above code inside ```next``` generate an iterator?

Comment: @tnq177 exactly, and `next()` would get the first iterator's value in this case, or throw the `StopIteration` exception.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot, mate. I've just tested and seen the result. It's way faster. I didn't know that above syntax generates an iterator. So what do we in list comprehension is basically converting an iterator into a list?

PS: I have to wait 7 more minutes to accept your answer.

Comment: @tnq177 in your case, you first form a complete list of files and then get the first result. In this case, there is an iterator build that then advances only a single time. You may also need to look at `glob.iglob` and try to use it with `next`: smth like `next(glob.iglob(join(path, ".*")))`.

Comment: using `next()` like this also works well with the newer [pathlib `Path.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob)

Comment: I'm surprised this is significantly faster, given that `listdir` makes a list already. How big is your directory?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
base_dir = "/path/to/dir"
list(filter(lambda f: os.path.isfile(f"{base_dir}/{f}"), os.listdir(base_dir)))[0]
```

Comment: Based on the presence of the outer list, I think you missed the point of the question.