# how to get only first filename in multiple same filename in directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Baiscally, i'm reading the filenames and taking the files which is matching the prefix value = 065572 in certain directory. So i'm having the file name as like below in same directory.

```
- image_read
    -065572_sometext.png
    -065572_file1_sometext_001.jpg
    -065572_file2_sometext_002.jpg
```

There are two cases
1. I want to take only first file name. `065572_sometext.png` . I got the solution for this in @illusion comment.
2. I want to take other two filenames. `065572_file1_sometext_001.jpg` , `065572_file2_sometext_002.jpg` . Can anyone help me out for this case.

For case(1), worked by below code

```
default =''
find_filename = [next((os.path.basename(x) for x in (glob.iglob('/home/username' + '/**/' + value + '*', recursive=True))),default)]
filename = ", ".join(find_filename)
filename_list.append(filename)
```

For case(2), i need a solution. How to handle it?

Comment: Not very robust, but you could include only filenames less than a certain length in your list comp, if all of your desired filenames are the same length `...if len(x)<=10...` (6 digits + file extension)

Comment: `filename_list[0]` accesses the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you want to get the name of the first file present in `image_read` folder which is `"065572_sometext.png"`, right?
To do this just write this:

```
default = "No files found" #value to return if no file found
first_file = next((join(path_to_image_read, f) for f in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))), default)
```

According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35114559/python-how-to-get-the-first-file-in-directory/35114568#35114568), if no files are found in the directory, in our case `image_read`, it'll throw `StopIteration` exception. So, either handle it, or provide a default value as above.

This means if no file is found in the `image_read` folder, it'll return `"No files found"` else it will return `"065572_sometext.png"`

Hope this helps

Comment: could you please explain "default value here" with my code or can u paste with some example?

Comment: I have made changes to the answer, hope it helps now...

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now its work fine as expected. I changed my code like `find_filename = [next((os.path.basename(x) for x in (glob.iglob('/home/username' + '/**/' + value + '*', recursive=True))),default)]`

Comment: Suppose if i want to get other filenames without first one, how to handle it?

Comment: all_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if isfile(join(path, f))]